# How to Add an existing xcDatamodel file to Object

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcdatamodel

I already have an existing xcdatamodel file. So I create a new project with core data. Now I want to replace the xcdatamodel file provided by the xcode with xcdatamodel file that I had.

How would I do that?

How would I know that my old xcdatamodel file will get compiled?

How should I modify the code around so that the xcode knows where to look.